# Mac FLASH projector (.app) with multiple SWF files inside

Tags: flash, macos

my project is made from multiple SWF files. I'm able to create .app from the main SWF file.

- Is it possible to put the related files into the .app directory structure?
- Where should be placed? Into .app/Contents/Resources/ ?
- Would it be possible to access these files using some relative path to this location from the main SWF?
- Is there someone who did it already?

Unfortunately I don't have Mac at this moment to test it.

Answer (score 1):

So I've got a Mac and made a simple test.. so finally it looks it's possible to put the external files into the .app/Contents/Resources/ folder and load them using relative path like:

```
loadMovie("./myMain.app/Contents/Resources/myExternalFile.swf");
```